# How to find missing number in a string of numbers with no separator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string consisting of some numbers, not separated by any separator. The numbers are positive integers and the sequence increases by one at each number except the missing number. The task is to find the missing number. The numbers will have no more than six digits. Print -1 if input sequence is not valid.

```
Input  : 89101113
Output : 12

Input  : 9899101102
Output : 100

Input  : 596597598600601602:
Output : 599

Input  : 909192939495969798100101
Output : 99

Input  : 11111211311411511
Output : -1
```

As far as I am aware, looping considers each character at a time.
Is this possible to achieve in python ?

Comment: The way you're presenting is not a sequence of *numbers*, it's a sequence of *digits* or a sequence of numbers that have at least one digit but possibly more - if more then how many digits?. If a number in a string has more than a single digit then you have to decide where one number stops and the other begins - otherwise there's no way to know if the string is one number or a sequence of integers. - if you assume 9899 has 98 and 99, you have to decide how you'll know it's not *989* and *9* or *9899* as single number, so you have to limit your operations somehow.

Comment: Great discussion @dmitryro, that was going to be along the lines of my thinking out loud: you have to determine what the first number is somehow and eliminate all possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

You can't simply loop over set sizes, you have parse, using a changing size.

Take `n` characters from the start of the string, convert them to `int`, add one, and check if it matches the new start of the string. If not, record that, add the characters back to the start of the string and try again. Repeat. If the number of non-matches gets greater than 1, stop, add one to `n`, and try the whole process again. If you get through a whole loop at `n` and the number of non-matches is 1, then you've found the correct answer.

```
def split(sequence, x):
    return sequence[:x], sequence[x:]

def parse(digits):
    """
    Try to parse "digits" into numbers, and find the missing one.

    The numbers will have no more than six digits.
    Return -1 if "digits" isn't parseable or isn't missing one.

    >>> parse("89101113")  # 8, 9, 10, (12), 13
    12
    >>> parse("9899101102")  # 98, 99, (100), 101, 102
    100
    >>> parse("596597598600601602")  # 596, 597, 598, (599), 600, 601, 602
    599
    >>> parse("909192939495969798100101")  # 90, ...
    99
    >>> parse("11111211311411511")  # Looks like "111, ..." but isn't
    -1
    """
    for n in range(1, 7):
        expected, remainder = split(digits, n)
        failures = []
        while len(failures) <= 1 and remainder:
            expected = str(int(expected) + 1)
            actual, remainder = split(remainder, len(expected))
            if actual != expected:
                failures.append(expected)
                remainder = actual + remainder  # Re-parse
        if len(failures) == 1:
            return int(failures[0])
    return -1
```

Comment: I did similar solution but my response failed when the sequence starts from `910111213` or `99100101102103` or `999100010011002`. Working thru that before I post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most readable, but seems to be working.  My basic logic was to use `str.index()` and a continually shortened string to check if the next expected number (for a given starting digit size) came at position `0`.  Do this until the original string is matched (in which case there are no missing numbers), but allow one chance for the expected number to be incremented (and then if the starting string gets matched, return that skipped number).  If more than one number needs to be skipped, move on to increasing the starting digit size.  Once the starting digit length gets too long (more than half of the input  digits), call it quits and return `-1`.  Some more comments below, happy to try and clean up or explain more:

```
def missing_digits(number):
    s = str(number)
    l = 1
    while True:                        # LOOP to increase starting number size
        if l > len(s)/2:               # return negative one if starting number gets too large
            return -1
        nextnum = int(s[:l])           # nextnum: next number to find
        s_test = s[len(str(nextnum)):] # s_test: running string to test against
        skips = 0                      # skips: how many numbers have been skipped
        lastskip = None                # lastskip: most recent skipped number (or None if no skips)
        while True:                    # LOOP to check each sequential number
            if len(s_test) == 0:       # return either None or the last skipped number if end of input reached
                return lastskip
            if skips > 1:              # stop if there is more than one number skipped
                break
            nextnum = nextnum + 1
            try:
                if s_test.index(str(nextnum)) == 0:      # use .index() to see if nextum occurs first
                    s_test = s_test[len(str(nextnum)):]  # continue if so and shorten s_test
                    continue
            except:                                      # if this fails or .index() of nextnum isn't first
                pass
            lastskip = nextnum                           # record the skup
            skips += 1
        l += 1
```

Testing:

```
for i in [89101113,
          9899101102,
          596597598600601602,
          909192939495969798100101,
          11111211311411511,
          123456]: # extra with no missing digits
    print(missing_digits(i))
```

Output:

```
12
100
599
99
-1
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Under limited digits
Use the preset difference table to speed up the search for the number to be carried
Example:
`9999-1000 = 8999` Find the table carry
This is much faster than checking the digit directly

```
CARRY_ARRAY = {-8, -89, -899, -8999, -89999, -899999, -7, -88, -898, -8998, -89998, -899998}


def check_lack(string):
    for b in range(1, 7):
        start, index = int(string[:b]), b
        while index < len(string):
            num = string[index:index + b]
            difference = int(num) - start
            if difference in CARRY_ARRAY:
                b += 1
                continue
            if difference == 1:
                start, index = start + 1, index + b
            elif difference == 2:
                return int(num) - 1
            else:
                break
    return -1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider adding explanations to your answers to improve their quality.